# Change the case of slide headings generated by org-reveal

Tags: org-mode, org-reveal

I'm using org-reveal to make a slide presentation. Several of the reveal themes appear to force headings to be shown on the html slides with all letters in uppercase.

Instead, I'd like the case in the html slide to be the same as in the .org file. Is there a straightforward way to do this (ideally as a configuration option rather than a custom css file)?

Comment: What themes do that?

Comment: Most, e.g. beige, black, moon. I think the only theme that doesn't is serif.

Answer (score 0):

Since the exporter does not change the case (at least in my simple experiments, there is no difference in the headings when I look at the HTML file), then it must be the JS or CSS that does that, so I suspect you will indeed have to modify the theme: I don't think you can do it with options on the Org mode side.

When I look into e.g. `moon.css`, I see this:

```css
.reveal h1,
.reveal h2,
.reveal h3,
.reveal h4,
.reveal h5,
.reveal h6 {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  color: #eee8d5;
  font-family: "League Gothic", Impact, sans-serif;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: none; }
```

I would try getting rid of that `text-transform` in the CSS file.